# Python number pyramid

Tags: python, numbers

I am trying to make number pyramid. But this codes is not good.

```py
print("Fourth Number Pattern")
lastNumber = 9
for i in range(1, lastNumber):
    for j in range(lastNumber-i):
        print(' ', end=' ')
    for j in range(1,i):
        if(lastNumber>=6):
           print(2**(j-1), end=' ')    
    for i in range(-1+i, -1, -1):
        print(format(2**i, "2d"), end=' ')

    print("")
```

How can I fix it? I tried use format(). I guess I used wrong.

I want to take like this output.

```
                  1
              1   2  1
           1  2   4  2  1
        1  2  4   8  4  2  1
      1 2  4  8  16  8  4  2 1
    1 2 4  8 16  32 16  8  4 2 1
  1 2 4 8 16 32  64 32 16  8 4 2 1
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
```

My output:

```
               1 
            1  2  1 
          1 2  4  2  1 
        1 2 4  8  4  2  1 
      1 2 4 8 16  8  4  2  1 
    1 2 4 8 16 32 16  8  4  2  1 
  1 2 4 8 16 32 64 32 16  8  4  2  1 
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 64 32 16  8  4  2  1
```

Comment: Please format your code better, right now it's a little hard to read.

Comment: Okey, 1 minute please :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `'\t'` instead of a single space between numbers`' '`

```
print("Fourth Number Pattern")
lastNumber = 9
for i in range(1, lastNumber):
    for j in range(lastNumber-i):
        print(' ', end='\t')
    for j in range(1,i):
        if(lastNumber>=6):
           print(2**(j-1), end='\t')    
    for i in range(-1+i, -1, -1):
        print(format(2**i, "2d"), end='\t')

    print("")
```

here is the output :

[image]

Comment: I can't open the picture. But I tried code. İt is not working.

Comment: Could it be related to the compiler use?

Comment: Ah okey. I opened picture. I want exactly like this. Where is the problem? I used your code.

Comment: @YusufUçan sagol abi ;)

Answer (score 1):

There where a couple of places where you where outputting 1 space in between numbers. I've added comments to the code below to indicate where this was happening. By changing the length of the space in between numbers to match the length of the longest number, we can make everything get displayed in nice even columns.

```
print("Fourth Number Pattern")
lastNumber = 9
length_of_longest_number = len(str( max(2 ** (9-2), 1) ))
s = length_of_longest_number # The number of spaces we will be putting in between numbers
for i in range(1, lastNumber):
    for j in range(lastNumber-i):
        print(' ' * s, end=' ') # Was outputting 1 space before
    for j in range(1,i):
        if(lastNumber>=6):
           print(format(2**(j-1), str(s)+"d"), end=' ') # Was outputting 1 space before
    for i in range(-1+i, -1, -1):
        print(format(2**i, str(s)+"d"), end=' ')

    print("")
```

Output:

```
                              1
                          1   2   1
                      1   2   4   2   1
                  1   2   4   8   4   2   1
              1   2   4   8  16   8   4   2   1
          1   2   4   8  16  32  16   8   4   2   1
      1   2   4   8  16  32  64  32  16   8   4   2   1
  1   2   4   8  16  32  64 128  64  32  16   8   4   2   1
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Also Mohsen_Fatemi solution is good. You can try it.